# Disabling time synchronisation in vm

Tags: virtualbox

I'd like to disable time synchronization from the VM in virtual box. I've found that the next commands have to be sent before launch the vm:

```
VBoxManage setextradata <YOUR_VM_NAME> "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled" 1

VBoxManage setextradata <YOUR_VM_NAME> "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution" 1
```

So, my question is: Do I have to launch these commands every time that I start the vm or only once?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the way to read the options with parameter "getextradata". So, the answer is that the options are stored after a reboot. So it is necessary to do it once.

VBoxManage getextradata "VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled"
VBoxManage getextradata "VBoxInternal/TM/TSCTiedToExecution"